# Verifone Printer Api (library)

Tags: android, printing, verifone

according to verifone's documentation[Verifone Printer Api](https://developer.verifone.com/docs/develop/develop-android-apps/api-documentation/printer-api)

the developer only needs to define this on build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile (name: 'DeveloperSDK-release.x.x.x', ext: 'aar')
}
```

I did what the documentation said, I have a CommercePlugin installed in my studio [Downloaded their SDK](https://developer.verifone.com/docs/overview/download-the-sdk), followed the steps, still no luck,

I even tried to manually copy paste the Carbon Api's aar, rename it, still no luck.

Do I have to request their Printer AAR file?
Any related experience here?

Comment: What have you actually added in your build.gradle for dependency? And what error do you actually get? What do you really mean by "no luck"?

Comment: I added what the documentation said DeveloperSDK-release-2.3.18, theres no error actually, the documentation says to put this in build gradle, and the Printer Api will be available, I also have a Commerce Plugin installed, studio gives an option to create a verifone project, But i just need to integrate the printer API into an existing one

Comment: Hi any luck with this i am also in similar situation.